# Discontinuous function

Tags: continuity, normed-spaces

Show that the function, $f:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$,
$$ f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 1, & \|(x,y)\|\geq1\\
 0, & \|(x,y)\|<1 \end{cases} $$
is not continuous ($\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R^2}$ have their usual Euclidean metrics).

Could someone check if my proof is correct. Feel like I might have overlooken some fact or left something out.

Let *d* and *p* be the metrics on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R^2}$ respectively and take $\alpha\in\mathbb{R^2}$ such that $\|\alpha\|=1$. So I have to show that there does not exist $\delta>0$ such that if *p*($(x,y),\alpha)<\delta$, then *d*($f(x,y),f(\alpha))<\epsilon$.

Take $\delta>0$ and let $\epsilon=1$. Let $(x,y)=\alpha-\delta\alpha\implies\|(x,y)\|=\|\alpha-\delta\alpha\|=\|\alpha(1-\delta)\|=|1-\delta|\|\alpha\|=|1-\delta|$ 
,
if $\delta\geq2$ it suffices to show _p_$((x,y),\alpha)<2\leq\delta\implies$_d_$(f(x,y),f(\alpha))<\epsilon$. Hence, for $\delta<2$, we get $\|(x,y)\|<1\implies f(x,y)=0\implies d(f(x,y),f(\alpha))=|0-1|\geq1.$ Therefore, the function is not continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the right idea, but your execution is a bit off. Take $w\in\Bbb R^2$ with $\lVert w\rVert=1,$ take any $\delta>0,$ put $\epsilon=1,$ and take $0<c<\min\{1,\delta\}.$ Then, put $v=(1-c)w,$ instead. You'll see that $\lVert v\rVert=|1-c|=1-c<1,$ so that $f(v)=0,$ and so $$d\bigl(f(v),f(w)\bigr)=1\ge\epsilon,$$ but also that $$p(v,w)=\lVert-cw\rVert=|c|\lVert w\rVert=|c|<\delta,$$ so the function is not continuous.

Comment: Yeah you're right about my execution. The 0<c<min{1,\delta} was a nice touch. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You are very welcome! Well done in coming up with the idea, as that's often the hardest part.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively; We have $\lim_n f(1-\frac{1}{n},0) = 0 \neq 1 = f(1,0)$. Since $(1-\frac{1}{n},0) \to f(1,0)$, $f$ cannot be continuous.